# Get element by position (X and Y) in react-native

Tags: react-native

On web, you can get any element by its position:

**[document.elementFromPoint(x, y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)**

Is there something similar in React Native? Can it be done with a native bridge (Java/Objective C)?

I would like to get an element on screen by position X and Y (Ignoring empty places and following transformation or styling calculations like padding, margin, borderRadius) then set it a [native prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation) or dispatch events.

OBS: I'm not referring to onLayout property or any other declared in the component's construction/render, my idea is from any X and Y position get an element that corresponds to these coordinates then get a reference to it. A use case for example: Create a virtual cursor that dispatch click events on correct components, following margin/padding and ignoring pointerEvents none.

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwBvi.png)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can get your current elements position in two ways,

1. onLayout
2. measure/measureInWindow/measureLayout (in this example
   triggered by click on the element)

**First way**: onLayout

```
const onLayout=(event)=> {
  const {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  console.log('onLayout:', x, y, width, height); 
};
```

**Second way**: start by assigning a ref to the element

```
const newRef = useRef();

const onButtonPress = () => {
  newRef?.current?.measureInWindow( (fx, fy, width, height) => {
    console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx);
    console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy);
    console.log('Component width is: ' + width);
    console.log('Component height is: ' + height);
  });        
};

return(
  <TouchableOpacity ref={newRef} onLayout={onLayout} onPress={onButtonPress} >

  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, newRef is always null (even with <TouchableOpacity ref={newRef} )

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks @gaurav-roy!

Comment: second way was what i needed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use onLayout prop of React Native components.
You should check this [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout)

Comment: onLayout is a property defined directly in the element declaration during rendering, if I want to get the reference of any element from its X and Y position, how it can be done?